# how to set system proxy from angular js app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, proxy, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating an app using node js and angular ui, where i need to ping a server.
To ping a server i have written the folloing code, which works perfectly :

```
app.get("/api/getPing", function (req, res) {
    var target = req.query.target;

    var hosts = [target];
    hosts.forEach(function (host) {
        ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
            if (isAlive) {
                res.send(true);
            }
            else {
                res.send(false);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

However i am unable to ping few server for which proxy setting is required. Could someone tell me how can i set the proxy using my app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which angular version are you using Angular 1.x or 2.x. Asking because Angular2 CLI provides a backend proxy

Comment: Hi Bernhard, unfortunately we are using Angular 1.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use *express-http-proxy*

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use('/proxy', proxy('www.google.com'));
```